# Redshift - Error using Case statement

Tags: sql, case, amazon-redshift

I am trying to check time since first call was made to a customer. I am checking this against current system time using a case statement.

```
select sale_id,case when ((CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - min(call_date) >= '500 days' THEN 'more than 500 days'
                    when ((CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - min(call_date) >= '300 days' THEN 'more than 300 days'
                    else 'Less than 300 days' end  as Aging
                    from sales
```

I keep getting Query execution failed. Invalid operation: syntax error at or neat "THEN".

I am using Amazon Redshift DB.
Could anyone assist.

Comment: Missing closing parentheses.

Comment: You also trying to compare time with string which is not valid

Comment: thanks my bad for missing the parenthesis..

Comment: @apomene: the comparison is correct. The result of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - min(call_date)` is an `interval` and `'500 days'` is valid literal for an interval

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the parentheses issue, you are also using `min()` with no `group by`.  I also doubt that `sale_id` represents a customer.

So, I suspect you want something like:

```
select customer_id,  -- or whatever the right column is
       (case when CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - min(call_date) >= '500 days' then 'more than 500 days'
             when CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - min(call_date) >= '300 days' then 'more than 300 days'
             else 'Less than 300 days'
        end)  as Aging
from sales 
group by customer_id;
```